# VirtualBox - USB Devices don't install correctly using Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, virtualbox

I am trying to install the drivers for my [HTC Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Magic) (2.1) and my [iPod Touch 3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch) 8GB (4.1), but when I plug them in, neither of them successfully install their drivers.

They work perfectly fine when running on Windows natively, why are they behaving like this on VirtualBox?

- I am using Windows 7 (AMD64) - natively and non natively.
- Ubuntu 10.10 - Also natively
- VirtualBox 4.0.0

Comment: which is the host and which is the guest?  usb passthrough doesn't work on the open source edition, only on the proprietary version of vbox.  and there is additional tweaking required to get it to work if ubuntu is the host and windows is the guest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using VirtualBox 4 (or above), and you need USB 2.0/3.0 support, be sure to install the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.0.0/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.0.0-69151.vbox-extpack) (all platforms). Beginning with v4, all external support and features will be provided as extension packs (read more in *[User Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing)*). You should install Extension Pack on the host with the same version as your installed version of VirtualBox.

Comment: Dumb question: should the extension pack be installed on the host or guest OS?

Comment: On the guest. And no question is dumb :)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the VirtualBox Extension Pack (can be downloaded from www.virtualbox.org) and enable USB 2.0 in the settings after doing that.

I had the same problem and this fixed it for me. I'm not sure why this is the case, but maybe the device support for USB below 2.0 is broken.